# Where can I find a shapefile of the UK electricity grid network?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data, europe, united-kingdom, utility-network

Does anyone know where can I download a shapefile with the UK electricity grid network?

Answer (score 5):

[**National Grid Transmission Network Shapefiles](https://www.nationalgrid.com/uk/electricity-transmission/network-and-infrastructure/network-route-maps)**

Available data:

- Over Head line
- Tower
- Substation Site
- Gas Site
- Gas Pipe
- Cable

Shapefiles are in the OSGB36 (Ordnance Survey National) projection.

Comment: The link above no longer works but I found the data here instead:
https://www.nationalgrid.com/uk/electricity-transmission/network-and-infrastructure/network-route-maps

Comment: @OliverBurdekin thanks looks like they went to https, have updated the link.